# How to draw only a part of a view background

Tags: android, view, draw

I need to draw only a part of a TextView. To do so I subclassed a TextView and overrided the onDraw method with the following code:

```
class DisappearingTextView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs) {
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        val cropRect = computeCropRect()
        canvas.clipRect(cropRect)
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
}
```

It works fine for the text but the background is still fully drawn. Is there any way to also partially draw the background?

Comment: Worst case you could also subclass your background drawable and clip the bounds to the crop rectangle as well.

Comment: I like this idea! Can you post it as an answer so if there is no better solution I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to override the draw() method instead of onDraw() because the background is drew before the call to onDraw(). Thanks Romain Guy for the solution and the explanation!